# Dynamically write parquets using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, parquet

Is there a way to dynamically size parquet output files on dataframe.write using pyspark?
We have a generic job that writes many tables to S3, some of those are small, but some are very big. How can I size the output using one job for all?

Comment: What do you mean by "size"..? The number of 'chunks' you get depends on the number of partitions the data you are saving is in.

Comment: I want to know if I can define that number of partition in execution time

Comment: [yes you can](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition)

Comment: sorry I was not clear, but what I need is to define this number according to the size of the dataframe, If the dataframe is bigger, I want the repartition to be bigger. In some cases thie repartition size will be 1.

Comment: I am not sure about getting the actual size of the df in memory, but I doubt you need to be very exact. You do something crude like `df.count() * len(df.columns)` to get a feel how many fields it has in total (or just count if all have the same schema)